# How to ingegrate sabre booking SOAP API into React Native

Tags: rest, api, soap, sabre

We are planning to use sabre SOAP api for booking 
https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/book_air_segment

as its not available for REST. we are using react native to build our app and want to use above API. we had tried to integrate SOAP api but it doesn't work.

Is there any one out there who have used SOAP api to book the flight or any other SOAP api with react native? is there REST api available for booking the flight?

any information will be really helpful

thank you

Comment: You can use the Orchestrated Rest API, which will allow you to book the flight

https://beta.developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record

Or you will have to form the XML and send it as a HTTP request using the SOAP Header.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to integrate a SOAP web service ( or any other ) you should separate concerns to different application layer. To make an example my approach would by

- Create a library that will be your simplified interface to the web service API, for example if the booking procedure is a subsequential call of remote services your library interface would be just $myClient->book($request). 
  Internally, the library will do all the calls that are necessary to make the job done.
- Create you application backend and have that library as dependency: in the application layer you will store in your database all the data you need, manage log, exceptions etc.
  This can be you JSON/REST API.
- Frontend application: this will just render the data given by your application backend, the data supplied by your backend will be as simple as possible, ready to be rendered in a fancy layout.
  For the frontend you can use any technology you like, Angular, React, Cordova etc..

Hope it helps

Cheers